# Why is my clock code slowing my website down

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I put together a basic clock to work with react hooks, but for some reason, kit really slows my website down.  Any reason why that would be?

```
function Welcome() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());
    setInterval(() => clock(), 1000);

    function clock() {
        setTime(new Date());
    }

    return (
        <WelcomeBox>
            <WelcomeTime>
                {date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                    hour: 'numeric',
                    minute: 'numeric',
                    hour12: true,
                })}
            </WelcomeTime>
        </WelcomeBox>
    );
}
```

Comment: You never cancel the intervals, and each tick will repeat *every* 1000ms. You'll end up with a *lot* of ticking.

Comment: Side note, you should change `setInterval(() => clock(), 1000);` to `setInterval(clock, 1000)`

Comment: Put a console.log in your clock() function to make sure you're calling it every 1000ms and no sooner. If your intervals are overlapping you'll see repeated console statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a new interval every time the component renders.

To properly do what I think you're trying to do, you need to put your setInterval inside a `useEffect` hook.

Like this:

```
function Welcome() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => clock(), 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])

    function clock() {
        setTime(new Date());
    }

    return (
        <WelcomeBox>
            <WelcomeTime>
                {date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                    hour: 'numeric',
                    minute: 'numeric',
                    hour12: true,
                })}
            </WelcomeTime>
        </WelcomeBox>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Don't start a timer every time the component renders

Instead, you should start the timer only once.

### Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

`setTimeout` waits the speficied amount of time, calls the callback, and goes away, while `setInterval` calls the callback over and over again with a delay between calls.

Here's an example

```
function Welcome() {
    // ...
    function clock() {
         setTime(new Date());
         setTimeout(clock, 1000);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then you can call clock() once to start the clock.

Comment: But if I clear the interval, what benefits will I get out of setTimeout over setInterval?